# private set(value) requires initilization before init{ }

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to add a `private set(value)` to a var, but this requires to init the field before `init { }` has run. Why?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello fellow Stackoverflowers!")

    val data = Data(listOf<Point>(Point(1, 1.0, 1.0), Point(2, 2.0, 2.0), Point(3, 3.0, 3.0)))
    val testInit = TestInit(data)

    testInit.magicMethod()
    println("Relevant Point Id: ${testInit.relevantPoint.id}")

}

class TestInit(val someData: Data) {

    var relevantPoint: Point //  = Point(0,0.0,0.0) // or do this, but why? It is set in init{}, lateinit also not allowed
//        private set  // this works
        private set(value) { // Why can't I do this? -> "Property must be initialized - Error"
            if (value.id < 100) 
                field = value
            else 
                field = someData.points.first()
        }

    init {
        if (someData.points.size < 3) // doing validation before setting the point
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Need at least three points!")

        relevantPoint = someData.points.first() // here the point gets initialized
    }

    fun magicMethod() {
        // do other calculations
        relevantPoint = someData.points[someData.points.size / 2] // just assign some point
    }

}

data class Data(var points: List<Point> = mutableListOf())

data class Point(val id: Int, val x: Double, val y: Double)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `relevantPoint = someData.points.first()`, the field will only get initialised if it's `id` is less than 100 (due to your setter logic). So there is a chance that you won't have initialised the field.

You can either use a backing field if you need to keep the initialisation in `init`, or simply initialise the value inline, which won't go through the setter:

```
var relevantPoint = someData.points.first()
    private set(value) {
        ...
    }
```

---

**Edit**

It's interesting that this problem occurs even after you adding an `else` branch to your setter and I am not sure why that is. However for a solution (if you can't initialise it as above) you can easily use a backing field:

```
private var _relevantPoint: Point
var relevantPoint: Point
    private set(value) {
        if (value.id < 100) _relevantPoint = value
    }
    get() = _relevantPoint

init {

    _relevantPoint = someData.points.first()
}
```

Comment: Bad example, I realize. I just wanted some logic in the setter. Take out the if statement (leaving field = value which would be default behavior). It still does not allow this.

Initializing like you propose will not work, because the list may be empty and is run before the init {} call which would raise an error.

Comment: Oh I see, how interesting, I would have expected it to allow it with the else branch. Hopefully someone can shed some light on why it doesn't allow it, meanwhile I've updated my answer to include the most elegant solution I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, variables must be either initialized on declaration or (only in case of `var`) get marked with `lateinit`.

According to the [Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html#checking-whether-a-lateinit-var-is-initialized):

> The modifier (`lateinit`) can be used on `var` properties declared inside the body of
> a class (not in the primary constructor, and only when the property
> ***does not*** have a custom `getter` or `setter`) as well as for top-level
> properties and local variables.

So You can't do The latter

Your best bet is what [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67447125/906137) suggested:

```
var relevantPoint = someData.points.first()
    private set(value) {
        if (value.id < 100)
            field = value
    }
```

The other option is that you don't use custom `setter` and check your criteria elsewhere.

Comment: Also here: initializing with someData.points.first() will not work if the list is empty: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
This is exactly the reason why I initialize the var in init after the check and not directly.

Comment: If you look at my code snippet I also commented that I could initialize with an empty point solving the issue while keeping the validation. I also commented that lateinit is also not possible, so I am not sure what help that peace of documentation should give.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is what was presented earlier.
But I thought of an alternative, this way.

```
data class Data(var points: List<Point> = mutableListOf())

data class Point(var id: Int, val x: Double, val y: Double)

class RelevantPoint(_point: Point) {
    var point: Point = _point
    set(value) {
        if (value.id < 100)
            field = value
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello fellow Stackoverflowers!")
    val data = Data(listOf<Point>(Point(1, 1.0, 1.0), Point(2, 2.0, 2.0), Point(3, 3.0, 3.0)))
    val testInit = TestInit(data)

    testInit.magicMethod()
    println("Relevant Point Id: ${testInit.relevantPoint.point.id}")
}

class TestInit(val someData: Data) {

    var relevantPoint: RelevantPoint

    init {
        if (someData.points.size < 3) // doing validation before setting the point
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Need at least three points!")

        relevantPoint = RelevantPoint(someData.points.first())
}

fun magicMethod() {
    // do other calculations
    relevantPoint.point = someData.points[someData.points.size / 2] // just assign some point
}
}
```

Comment: In your case the code in set(value) is never reached. Thus wrong logic.
In my case an approach with another class is also not suitable, because instead of if (value.id < 300) I access a number of variables and methods in the original class to trigger update of connected data.

Comment: In this suggestion the method set(value) will be reached at this point: 
relevantPoint.point = someData.points [someData.points.size / 2]